# How to handle response in json object in android

Tags: android, response, json

I am getting this response, which I don't know how to handle without an array:

```
{
    "1": {
        "entity_id": "1",
        "attribute_set_id": "4",
        "type_id": "simple"
    },
    "2": {
        "entity_id": "2",
        "attribute_set_id": "4",
        "type_id": "simple"
    },
    "5": {
        "entity_id": "5",
        "attribute_set_id": "4",
        "type_id": "simple"
    }
}
```

Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: how you handle it depends on what information you need.
to me this is all nonsense so id probably just ignore it.
nothing to do here without further information on whats important and whats not

Comment: Why would you do an "array"? This is an object, not an array.

Comment: I must have to handle this with only object, the web service response are not coming in array.

Comment: @ShoebAhmedSiddique : That is valid JSON. It's simply a JSON object which contains multiple name/value pairs where the values are also JSON objects.

Comment: @Squonk Thanks. But can you provide me code for handle this.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm

Just go through this for JSON Parsing.

you have get JsonObject like

```
JSONObject result=new JSONObject("your result"); //your json value as parameter
JsonObject obj= originalObject.getString("1");
```

Comment: The issue is not to handle response, actually the keys are not "1" , "2" and "5" all time the keys are unknown for us.

Comment: Then you cannot handle it. Until and unless you make it as JsonArray.

Comment: If it as array, you can get using JsonArray count.